# typescript interface require one of two properties to exist, any way to make compatible with parameter destructuring

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, interface require one of two properties to exist, any way to make compatible with parameter destructuring

```
interface IBase {
    text: string;
}

interface IColor extends IBase {
    color: string;
}

interface ISize extends IBase {
    size: number;
}

type IProps = ISize | IColor;

function getSth(value: IProps) {

    // error
    const { color, size, text } = value;

    console.log(text, color || size);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a `Type Guard` to fix this issue. For example, we can create a 'User Defined Type Guards' to check whether an object implements an interface as `isIColor` below.

```
interface IBase {
    text: string;
}

interface IColor extends IBase {
    color: string;
}

interface ISize extends IBase {
    size: number;
}

type IProps = ISize | IColor;

// type guard for IColor
function isIColor(arg: any): arg is IColor {
    return arg && arg.color;
}

function getSth(value: IProps) {
    if (isIColor(value)) {
        // value implements IColor interface
        let {color, text} = value;
        console.log(text, color)
    } else {
        let {size, text} = value;
        console.log(text, size)
    }
    // error
    // const { color, size, text } = value;

    // console.log(text, color || size);
}
```

For more documentation about how Type Guard works, you can refer to [this post](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard#user-defined-type-guards)